# HTML table border top 2 px

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a double border at my headcell, but finding it difficult without using any background images. Is it possible?

Now I have border top with white color, but I also want grey color over the white. So it is something like border-top ccc and fff.

**What I have**

[image]

**What I want**

[image]

**My HTML & CSS:**

```css
table.hor-zebra {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: #cccccc 1px solid;
}

table.hor-zebra>thead {
  border-top: #cccccc 1px solid;
}

table.hor-zebra>thead>tr>th {
  background: #e2e2e2;
  border-top: #ffffff 1px solid;
  border-bottom: #cccccc 1px solid;
  padding: 4px;
  color: #000;
}

table.hor-zebra>tbody>tr>td {
  background: #f3f3f3;
  border-bottom: #cccccc 1px solid;
  padding: 8px 4px 8px 4px;
}

table.hor-zebra>tbody>tr>td.odd {
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border-bottom: #cccccc 1px solid;
}

table.hor-zebra>tbody>tr:hover td {
  background: #faf4f2;
}
```

```html
<table class="hor-zebra">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">
        <span>Title</span>
      </th>
      <th scope="col">
        <span>Date</span>
      </th>
      <th scope="col">
        <span>Actions</span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td class="odd">
        <a href="x">x</a>
      </td>
      <td class="odd">
        <span>2017-10-30 19:06:27</span>
      </td>
      <td class="odd">
        <span>
   <a href="index.php?open=pages&amp;page=edit_page&amp;page_id=1&amp;editor_language=en">Edit</a>
   &middot;
   <a href="index.php?open=pages&amp;page=delete_page&amp;page_id=1&amp;editor_language=en">Delete</a>
   </span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="x">awd</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>2017-10-30 19:06:35</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>
   <a href="index.php?open=pages&amp;page=edit_page&amp;page_id=2&amp;editor_language=en">Edit</a>
   &middot;
   <a href="index.php?open=pages&amp;page=delete_page&amp;page_id=2&amp;editor_language=en">Delete</a>
   </span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="odd">
        <a href="x">awd</a>
      </td>
      <td class="odd">
        <span>2017-10-30 19:14:53</span>
      </td>
      <td class="odd">
        <span>
   <a href="index.php?open=pages&amp;page=edit_page&amp;page_id=3&amp;editor_language=en">Edit</a>
   &middot;
   <a href="index.php?open=pages&amp;page=delete_page&amp;page_id=3&amp;editor_language=en">Delete</a>
   </span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="x">awd</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>2017-10-30 19:15:07</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>
   <a href="index.php?open=pages&amp;page=edit_page&amp;page_id=4&amp;editor_language=en">Edit</a>
   &middot;
   <a href="index.php?open=pages&amp;page=delete_page&amp;page_id=4&amp;editor_language=en">Delete</a>
   </span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="odd">
        <a href="x">awd</a>
      </td>
      <td class="odd">
        <span>2017-10-30 19:16:47</span>
      </td>
      <td class="odd">
        <span>
   <a href="index.php?open=pages&amp;page=edit_page&amp;page_id=5&amp;editor_language=en">Edit</a>
   &middot;
   <a href="index.php?open=pages&amp;page=delete_page&amp;page_id=5&amp;editor_language=en">Delete</a>
   </span>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

I know that CSS can do it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to reset  `border-spacing:0;` instead `border-collapse:collapse;` else `th` borders and `table` borders collapse and only the white `th` borders are shown ....

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#value-def-table , https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/border-collapse

> `border`
>
> The various border properties apply to columns only if `border-collapse` is set to `collapse` on the `table` element. In that case, borders set on columns and column groups are input to the conflict resolution algorithm **that selects the border styles at every cell edge**.

```css
table.hor-zebra {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border-spacing:0;
  border: #cccccc 1px solid;
}

table.hor-zebra>thead {
  border-top: #cccccc 1px solid;
}

table.hor-zebra>thead>tr>th {
  background: #e2e2e2;
  border-top: #ffffff 1px solid;
  border-bottom: #cccccc 1px solid;
  padding: 4px;
  color: #000;
}

table.hor-zebra>tbody>tr>td {
  background: #f3f3f3;
  border-bottom: #cccccc 1px solid;
  padding: 8px 4px 8px 4px;
}

table.hor-zebra>tbody>tr>td.odd {
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border-bottom: #cccccc 1px solid;
}

table.hor-zebra>tbody>tr:hover td {
  background: #faf4f2;
}
```

```html
<table class="hor-zebra">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">
        <span>Title</span>
      </th>
      <th scope="col">
        <span>Date</span>
      </th>
      <th scope="col">
        <span>Actions</span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td class="odd">
        <a href="x">x</a>
      </td>
      <td class="odd">
        <span>2017-10-30 19:06:27</span>
      </td>
      <td class="odd">
        <span>
   <a href="index.php?open=pages&amp;page=edit_page&amp;page_id=1&amp;editor_language=en">Edit</a>
   &middot;
   <a href="index.php?open=pages&amp;page=delete_page&amp;page_id=1&amp;editor_language=en">Delete</a>
   </span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="x">awd</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>2017-10-30 19:06:35</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>
   <a href="index.php?open=pages&amp;page=edit_page&amp;page_id=2&amp;editor_language=en">Edit</a>
   &middot;
   <a href="index.php?open=pages&amp;page=delete_page&amp;page_id=2&amp;editor_language=en">Delete</a>
   </span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="odd">
        <a href="x">awd</a>
      </td>
      <td class="odd">
        <span>2017-10-30 19:14:53</span>
      </td>
      <td class="odd">
        <span>
   <a href="index.php?open=pages&amp;page=edit_page&amp;page_id=3&amp;editor_language=en">Edit</a>
   &middot;
   <a href="index.php?open=pages&amp;page=delete_page&amp;page_id=3&amp;editor_language=en">Delete</a>
   </span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <a href="x">awd</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>2017-10-30 19:15:07</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>
   <a href="index.php?open=pages&amp;page=edit_page&amp;page_id=4&amp;editor_language=en">Edit</a>
   &middot;
   <a href="index.php?open=pages&amp;page=delete_page&amp;page_id=4&amp;editor_language=en">Delete</a>
   </span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="odd">
        <a href="x">awd</a>
      </td>
      <td class="odd">
        <span>2017-10-30 19:16:47</span>
      </td>
      <td class="odd">
        <span>
   <a href="index.php?open=pages&amp;page=edit_page&amp;page_id=5&amp;editor_language=en">Edit</a>
   &middot;
   <a href="index.php?open=pages&amp;page=delete_page&amp;page_id=5&amp;editor_language=en">Delete</a>
   </span>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

`table {
    border-top: 2px solid black;
}`

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-top

Answer (score 0):

In satisation where you need to something before a child element, you can use Pseudo :before.

Try This:

```
table.hor-zebra>thead>tr>th {
 background: #e2e2e2;
 border-top: #ffffff 3px solid;
 border-bottom: #cccccc 1px solid;
 padding: 4px;
 color: #000;
 posistion:relative;
 }
table.hor-zebra>thead>tr>th:before{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  height:2px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:#cccccc;
  top:-1px;
  left:-1px;
}
```